# Linking errors when building Debug

Tags: visual-c++, linker, linker-errors, debug-symbols

Whenever I build my code in Release, it compiles and runs fine. However, when I switch to Debug, I get some errors that I can't seem to figure out.

```
swift.lib(scene.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>swift.lib(fileio.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>swift.lib(mesh_utils.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>swift.lib(object.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>swift.lib(mesh.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>swift.lib(pair.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>swift.lib(lut.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in main.obj
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in main.obj
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl std::uncaught_exception(void)" (?uncaught_exception@std@@YA_NXZ) already defined in libcpmtd.lib(uncaught.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in main.obj
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) already defined in main.obj
```

A bunch more of those and then...

```
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(char const *)" (??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fgetc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fgetc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fputc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fputc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _ungetc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(ungetc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __lock_file already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __unlock_file already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _setvbuf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(setvbuf.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _strncmp already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strncmp.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _memcpy_s already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memcpy_s.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fwrite already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fwrite.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fgetpos already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fgetpos.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __fseeki64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fseeki64.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fsetpos already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fsetpos.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fclose already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fclose.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>C:\...\: fatal error     LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I am using both the SWIFT and OPCODE libraries. I have "Runtime Library" field in C++->Code Generation the same for all 3 projects (my main project, swift, opcode). I have tried setting them all to \MT and all to \MD for Debug mode and neither work. Actually, when it builds successfully in Release, I have to set Opcode and my active project to \MD (swift can be either \md or \mt and it still builds). I don't really understand the runtime library for linking very well...so if this is the issue, can you try to be explicit?

I also went looking for _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL, but couldn't find it. Where should this be located for me to change it? I can't find it anywhere in the source. I don't see it in the project properties, but it's perfectly plausible that I am just not looking in the right place in the properties.

Apparently people have had similar errors with mis-matching Character sets. I have tried setting them all to multi and all to unicode. That didn't seem to have any effect.

Currently, my active project only has swift.lib as an additional dependency. I have the opcode.dll and opcode_d.dll so I don't statically link those.

In the Preprocessor under C/C++ settings, I have the following Preprocessor Definitions:

Opcode:

```
WIN32
_DEBUG
_WINDOWS
_USRDLL
OPCODE_EXPORTS
```

SWIFT:

```
_DEBUG
WIN32
_LIB
LOOKUP_TABLE_5_625
```

Active project:

```
WIN32
_DEBUG
_CONSOLE
```

I can provide more information if needed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already ensured that the C Runtime Library (CRT) is consistent for all projects, which is the preferred practice.  It is less important for your DLL project since it uses an independent copy of the CRT.

The next step is to look in the "Preprocessor" page of the projects' settings.  You are looking for preprocessor (macro) definitions which could conflict across the three projects.  I believe you will find _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL in that list.

I don't know how to post a follow-up question on StackOverflow, but you could add to your question the macro definitions that you find in each project.

Comment: I don't see the _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL macro in there, but I have updated the question with the macros in each project.